# How to check value of innerText if is null

Tags: javascript

I am developing a web scrapping and I am trying to solve latest problems with this.

In this case I need to check if innerText is null inside loop.

```
for(var j = 0; j<linkPlayersNew.length;j++){
                var stats = [];
                for (let i = 2; i <= 23; i++) { 
                    const values = await page.evaluate((nth,nth2) => {
                        const test= parseInt(nth);
                        const test2= parseInt(nth2);                                    
                        return document.querySelector('div.ui-table__row:nth-child('+test2+') > div:nth-child('+test+')').innerText;
                    },i,j+1);
                    stats.push(values);                     
                }           
                data.push(stats);                   
            }
            
            console.log(data);
```

This works correct but I need to check if innerText is not null inside loop.

Comment: and what if it is null?

Comment: If you always want a string, even in the case of `null`, then: `return document.querySelector('...')?.innerText ?? ''`

Comment: @jsejcksn Sweet tip! This null coalescing solves a lot of headaches